# VScode editor .xml file extension to show html file inside editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm new to vscode editor, I need below functionality to extended vscode editor.

How to render and display html file inside a vscode editor depending on file extension type.

Suppose following is the folder structure.

```
> MyProject[folder]
   > src[folder]
   > lib[folder]
   > package.json[file]
   > config.xml[file]
```

When user clicks on config.xml file I want to open an index.html file inside vscode editor(may be in preview window or any other option). Html file should be displayed as how it displays in browser inside vscode not as how editor displays as an editing html file.

Comment: You want to **edit** the XML code in rendered view or just display it?

Comment: on click of .xml file extension I want to display html file in preview window

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this：
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors
You can completely customize the editor you want, combined with `html+css` to display files in any format. The specific display method of the file needs to be written by yourself.